# Animation for Rows/Columns in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying out and learning Jetpack Compose. There I have

```
Columns {
   //..
}
```

or

```
Rows{
   //..
}
```

with simple UI elements like `ImageView`s, which are then shown horizontically or vertically. I already navigate through for instance a row and highlight currently selected `ImageView`.

My intention is I would like to select an `ImageView` in that row and change its position somewhere else in that row ... with an animation:

1. Navigate to a `ImageView` with left and right arrowkeys (already done)
2. Select currently with e.g. enter key (already done)
3. Animation: Selected `ImageView` (from step 2) shall move slightly up
4. Animation: Press left and right to move up animated `ImageView` (from step 3) to indicate new position. I would also change that image views opacity.
5. Animation: I also think of to separate adjacent `ImageViews` to indicate where to drop the previously selected `ImageView`.

Since I am new to Composables, I've heard something about `Modifier.animations()`, but I do not really know the best way to realize the animations in step 3-5? Maybe there is an example app/project with nice animations?!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation